# SVProgressHUD not displaying until UITableView is displayed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, svprogresshud

I am trying to use the SVProgressHUD to indicate that the app is busy.

My code is now:

```
        SVProgressHUD.show()
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            parser.parse()
            print("start reloading")
            self.protocolTableView.reloadData()

            print("end reloading")
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
        }
```

I get this warning:

```
UITableView.reloadData() must be used from main thread only
```

And it takes quite a while before the tableView is displayed after the parsing has been done.

How can I update the tableView after reading in the parsing from the main thread?

Thanks,
Bart

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but can you try putting the show() method in the prepareForSegue method? Or I think you could try running the show() call in the main thread..

Comment: I updated the code to move it to prepareForSegue(), but it seems that it is only executed on the main thread until the viewDidLoad() has finished.

Comment: `SVProgressHUD.show()` already adds itself to main queue, no need to do it explicitly once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XMLParser.parse` can block the UI. Try doing that on a background thread:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    parser.parse()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

UI updates should be done in main thread:

```
SVProgressHUD.show()
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    parser.parse()
    print("start reloading")

    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
        self.protocolTableView.reloadData()
        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.protocolTableView.reloadData()
        }
```

Reload tableView in Main Thread.

Comment: For me it worked only properly when using DispatchQueue.main.sync instead of DispatchQueue.main.async

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:

```
SVProgressHUD.show()
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    parser.parse()

    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
        self.protocolTableView.reloadData()
    }

    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
}
```

Thanks for all the help!!